# Azure Function written in Powershell that returns a JObject

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am writing an Azure Function in Powershell that will be invoked from Azure Data Factory. ADF requires that Functions return a JObject. Can someone please supply (or point me to) a short, complete Function script that does this?

I tried adding this line to the starter template that Azure generates, but this is from C# and obviously not correct for Powershell.

```
return new OkObjectResult( new { StatusCode = $status, Body = $body });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George Chen got me over the hump. My final solution is below. I verified that this works with Data Factory for both success and error responses.

```
$body = $('{ "functionReturnMsg":"'  + $msg + '" }')

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{ 
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body   # Data Factory wants this in JSON
    })
```

The ADF documentation makes this sound more complicated than it really is.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want powershell function return a json object, you could just use `ConvertFrom-Json` or `ConvertTo-Json` to convert between object and string.

Actually if your body is in json-format string, it will be OK.

```
$body = '{ "key1":"value1", "Key2":"value2" }'

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```

[image]

If I misunderstand, please let me know, hope this could help you.